# Result of glReadPixels() right after glFramebufferTexture2D()

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, gpgpu

I successfully use FBOs as a rendering destination in my code. It is not clear to me however what results I can expect when I do:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, someRgbaTexture, 0);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, *someRgbaBuffer);
```

in OpenGL ES 2.0 (assuming that the FBO is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE).
My goal is to get the content of the texture referenced by `someRgbaTexture`. Desktop OpenGL has the glGetTexImage() function for that purpose but it doesn't exist in ES.
Setting `someRgbaTexture` as read-texture, then doing a screen-filling textured quad into another FBO target, then reading back would sure do the trick, but I want to avoid that extra pass.
Therefore: Are the contents of the framebuffer equal to the contents of the texture after a call to `glFramebufferTexture2D()` or does that call just mean that any future render operation will target the specified texture?
If it's the latter: what would happen if my render operation just writes a single pixel or nothing at all? What would be the guarantees on the content in `someRgbaTexture` then?

Comment: FBO are not supposed to be used like this. See this [page](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/index.html)

Comment: @Fabien R, please add a more detailed explanation to your comment and describe what exactly one is supposed to find at [songho](http://www.songho.ca) that would answer the above question.

Comment: On the page describing FBOs, you will find example codes. It will give you hints about how FBOs work.

Comment: Just to be clear: I successfully use FBOs in my code as a rendering destination (as songho explains it). This is however not what my question was about.

Comment: I misunderstood you then because calling `glReadPixels()` after `glFramebufferTexture2D()` is a bit surprising. Where do you bind your buffer ? Can you show the complete rendering sequence ?

Comment: The code included is just a section, omitting everything not directly related to the question for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

This looks completely legal, and should give you the content of the texture as the result of `glReadPixels()`.

On page 114 of the ES 2.0 spec, in the explanation of `glFramebufferTexture2D()`, the description includes:

> No change is made to the state of the texture object

This means that if the texture previously had a well defined content, it still has that content after `glFramebufferTexture2D()`. And since it's now the color buffer of the current framebuffer, its content will be read by `glReadPixels()`.